# Single listclick does not get executed, but longclick does

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having a ListFragment with a list, that does not get single clicks. But long clicks are recognised.

```
        ListView listView = getListView();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {
                Log.i(null, "single click does NOT work.");
            }
        });

 // contextual action bar (CAB).
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {
                Log.i(null, "does work.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: REALLY STRANGE!!! try `listView.setClickable(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and was resolved by invalidating the listview's views when created and after scroll

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if ( scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE )
        {
          listView.invalidateViews();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}
});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Make your activity extends from **Activity** and not ListActivity or something like that ;)

Comment: OP get Listview object.so its not matter.